# What is the best strategy to upgrade Polymer 1.6.x components to version 3?

Tags: polymer, upgrade

We have a lot of components that are written in 1.6.x and we plan to upgrade them all the way to Polymer 3. I have read the upgrades guides from Polymer, but I can only see guides for 1.x to 2 and 2.x to 3, but not from 1.x to 3.

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade

https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/upgrade

What is the best strategy to upgrade Polymer 1.6.x components to version 3?

So far from reading in each guide, I should either upgrade the components to 2.x legacy or 2.x class based components. Not hybrid, since I'm not planning to support 1.x anymore. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each type? I'm looking for the quickest way to update the components since we have a limited team and timeframe. Does Polymer 3 support each type, assuming after we run the components through the Polymer modulizer tool? Thanks in advance!